# Is there any way to style a <svg> fill property inside a <p> tag using just one modifier without violating the BEM CSS principles?

Tags: css, svg, css-selectors, bem

I wonder if I could style `<svg>` `fill` color with just `paragraph--color` modifier.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Teste</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class="paragraph paragraph--color">
      <svg fill="red" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path
          fill-rule="evenodd"
          d="M10 9a3 3 0 100-6 3 3 0 000 6zm-7 9a7 7 0 1114 0H3z"
          clip-rule="evenodd"
        ></path>
      </svg>
      SVG and text should change color with paragraph--color modifier only.
    </p>
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      body {
        display: flex;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        background-color: whitesmoke;
        font-size: 20px;
        height: 100vh;
      }

      .paragraph {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        margin: auto;
      }

      .paragraph--color {
        color: blue;
      }
    </style>
  </body>
</html>
```

I could style `svg` `fill` color using

```
.paragraph--color svg {
  fill: blue;
}
```

but I would be violating BEM CSS principles.

Is there any way to do this without violating BEM principles and with no new classes added to  just by using pseudo classes and pseudo selectors?

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the SVG's fill as `currentColor` then set the `color` on `.paragraph--color` to what you want the fill to be. This works with `stroke-color` for SVG as well.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 100vh;
}

.paragraph {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.paragraph--color {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p class="paragraph paragraph--color">
  <svg fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path
          fill-rule="evenodd"
          d="M10 9a3 3 0 100-6 3 3 0 000 6zm-7 9a7 7 0 1114 0H3z"
          clip-rule="evenodd"
        ></path>
      </svg> SVG and text should change color with paragraph--color modifier only.
</p>
```